# 2D array not populating correctly or...? C++

Tags: c++

I have a serious problem that I just can't seem to solve. I apologize if it's a really newbie-like problem.

```
srand(117);
//enumeration type to keep track of which fish is which
enum CellState {EMPTY, FISH, SHARK};

//Creating the grid
CellState fishGrid[MAX_X][MAX_Y];
for(int m = 0; m < MAX_X; ++m)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < MAX_Y; ++n)
    {
        int num = rand() % 2;
        if(num == 0)
            fishGrid[m][n] = EMPTY;
        else
        {
            num = rand() % 2;
            if(num == 0)
                fishGrid[m][n] = SHARK;
            else
                fishGrid[m][n] = FISH;
        }
    }
}
//calculate how many on grid
if(stepsTaken % 5 == 0)
    {
        int fishAmount = 0;
        int sharkAmount = 0;

        for(int m = 0; m < MAX_X; m++)
        {
            for(int n = 0; n < MAX_Y; n++)
            {
                if(fishGrid[m][n] = FISH)
                    fishAmount++;
                else if(fishGrid[m][n] = SHARK)
                    sharkAmount++;
            }
        }
        cout << "FISH: " << fishAmount << endl
        << "SHARKS: " << sharkAmount << endl << endl;
```

For some reason, the output is always:
FISH: 100
SHARKS: 0

I don't necessarily understand. Would someone be able to please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`=` designates *assignment* operator in C++. Which means that what you have here

```
            if(fishGrid[m][n] = FISH)
                fishAmount++;
            else if(fishGrid[m][n] = SHARK)
                sharkAmount++;
```

uses *assignment* operator inside `if` conditions. By the above you override your entire grid with `FISH` values.

Equality comparison in C++ is performed by `==` operator. But you already know that, since you already use `==` in your `num` comparisons. Why are you using `=` in these grid comparisons then?

Comment: protip: putting the constant on the LEFT side will make compilation errors out of this kind of typo, e.g. if(FISH = fishGrid[m][n]) ...